# Kotlin equivalent for Optional::map in Java8

Tags: kotlin, nullable

Do you know if there is a shortcut for:

```
if (x == null) null else f(x)
```

For Java  `Optional` you can just do:

```
x.map(SomeClass::f)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kotlin utilizes its own approach to the idea of `Option`, but there're `map`, `filter`, `orElse` equivalents:

```
val x: Int? = 7                 // ofNullable()

val result = x
  ?.let(SomeClass.Companion::f) // map()
  ?.takeIf { it != 0 }          // filter()
  ?: 42                         // orElseGet()
```

I ended up writing a [full comparison here](http://4comprehension.com/kotlins-java-util-optional-equivalents/):

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `let` ([link to documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)):

```
x?.let(SomeClass::f)
```

### Example

```
fun f(n: Int): Int {
    return n+1
}

fun main(s: Array<String>) {
    val n: Int? = null
    val v: Int? = 3

    println(n?.let(::f))
    println(v?.let(::f))
}
```

This code prints:

```
null
4
```

Comment: I really don't understand why your answer has a downvote... But don't worry I think and I checked that your answer is also ok, it's a plus one (Y)

Comment: @DamianLattenero I don't get it, too, actually! But the same applies to your answer as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use let in this case, like this:

```
fun f(x : Int) : Int{
    return x+1
}

var x : Int? = 1
println(x?.let {f(it)} )

=> 2

x = null
println(x?.let {f(it)} )

=> null
```

and as @user2340612 mentioned, it is also the same to write:

```
println(x?.let(::f)
```