# What's the idiomatic Kotlin way to write `if...else null` as part of ?./?: chains?

Tags: kotlin, idioms

(Edited for clarity)

I keep finding myself writing `(if (x) f() else null) ?: (if (y) g() else null) ?: (if (z) h() else null)` and similar and I'm sure I'm not the only oneץ

I'm always reaching for a function like `valueIf` defined below (which is `takeIf` with order of parameters reversed so the value is lazy) , which would let me write code like `getViewEventType2()` instead of code like `getViewEventType1()` (both elaborated below).

Is there an idiom I'm missing?

(Also, is the compiler smart about functions like this, or should I fear creating too many temporary closures?)

```
    private fun getViewEventType1(): String? {
        return if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW") {
            intent.data?.pathSegments?.let {
                if (it.size == 3 && it[0] == "app" && it[1] == "event") it[2]
                else null
            }
        } else null
    }

    private fun getViewEventType2(): String? {
        return valueIf(intent.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW") {
            intent.data?.pathSegments?.let {
                valueIf(it.size == 3 && it[0] == "app" && it[1] == "event") { it[2] }
            }
        }
    }

    inline fun <T> valueIf(condition: Boolean, func: () -> T?) =
            if (condition) func() else null
```

Comment: The example here, and the linked write-up may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466874/44615

Comment: I don't get it - what exactly are you asking? Both of  those appear to be fine.

Comment: @MartinStone the linked write-up is about the great story `Kotlin` has for working with chains of calls on nullable values. I'm asking about how to combine conditions into these chains. `func().takeIf{condition}` would work but it doesn't short circuit (and it reverses your code).

Comment: @Zoe I'm asking if there's an idiom I'm missing, a function like my `valueIf()` already in the Kotlin stdlib or any other idiomatic way to do write this function

Comment: Because I keep finding myself writing `(if (x) f() else null) ?: (if (y) g() else null) ?: (if (z) h() else null)` and similar and I'm sure I'm not the only one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `takeIf()` to achieve what you want, like shown here in an extension function on `Intent`:

```
fun Intent.getViewEventType(): String? {
    return takeIf { it.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW" }
        ?.`data`
        ?.pathSegments
        ?.takeIf { it.size == 3 && it[0] == "app" && it[1] == "event" }
        ?.get(2)
}
```

Edit by OP: this is the final code I went with:

```
fun getViewEventType(): String? {
    return intent.takeIf { it.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW" }
            ?.`data`
            ?.pathSegments
            ?.takeIf { it.size == 3 && it[0] == "app" && it[1] == "event" }
            ?.get(2)
}
```

Comment: Ooh, this feels very idiomatic, thanks. So the trick is to start with a value I'm going to dig into (`intent`) and start filtering and transforming it (`intent.takeIf{...}?.let{it...}?.takeIf{...}`). I didn't think of my code as acting *on intent*, but it is.

Comment: Exactly, you got the idea. And using `?.` will ensure that the first `null` result will be returned without evaluating the rest of the chain.

Comment: And e.g. `(if (x) f() else null) ?: (if (y) g() else null) ?: (if (z) h() else null)` would translate to `f.takeIf{x}?.let{it()} ?: g.takeIf{y}?.let{it()} ?: h.takeIf{z}?.let{it()}` (or the same with `0.takeIf{x}?.let{f()}`)

Comment: You may even want to omit the `let` here... e.g.: `fun Intent.getViewEventType() = takeIf { it.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW" }
            ?.\`data\`?.pathSegments
            ?.takeIf { it.size == 3 && it[0] == "app" && it[1] == "event" }
            ?.get(2)`... Of course at least with appropariate new lines ;-)

Comment: @Roland Absolutely, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I added it also as an answer now because the comment just looked ugly ;-) should have waited a bit :-) but I also find the destructuring makes the `takeIf` even more readable... but in the end, it's not needed... `takeIf` is the key here :-)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [Wangs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55936527/6202869): [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) is the way to go for such constructs.

I will just leave the rest here for anyone interested (as my comment there was already applied): you may want to omit the `let` in favor of the [safe operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls). Additionally you may also be interested in [destructing declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), which makes it a bit more readable in my opinion:

```
fun Intent.getViewEventType() : String? = takeIf { it.action == "android.intent.action.VIEW" }
        ?.`data`?.pathSegments
        ?.takeIf { it.size == 3 }
        ?.takeIf { (source, actionType) -> // destructuring in action... you may want to name the variables appropriately
            source == "app" && actionType == "event"
        }
        ?.get(2)
```

I also used a [single expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) here, but I leave that up to you. As you are chaining a lot here you may at least want to specify the return type when using such a construct (which you could also omit).